# i want to store user clicks in database using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

My users table field is id,name,twitter and clicks
(clicks is hidden )

Logic is : whenever user clicks on another users twitter id then it should be counted and then new updated click should be stored in database.
i can do above logic.

But i don't know that how to detect clicks made by mouse on any link.
I mean
If the link is http://www.twitter.com/twitter now if user clicks on that link then clicks of that link should be increased by 2.
please provide me proper info for it.
any help ?

Update:

```
    <?php 

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("users", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `users`
ORDER BY `users`.`clicks` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['id'] . " <a href=" . $row['twitter']." target='_blank'>".$row['clicks']."</a>";
  echo "<br />";
  }
// some click detection code may be here..


mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Just any one tell me that how to store clicks in variable from $row['clicks']
if jquery is needed, then pls provide proper code that best match my above code.

Comment: Please EDIT your question rather than adding the code as a comment.  It hurts my head.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to create a redirection page to store the clicks...
modify the link to this... (check the echo or copy paste, i hope it works flawlessly)

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("users", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `users`
ORDER BY `users`.`clicks` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<a href="redirect.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" target="_blank">'. $row['clicks'] .'</a>';
    echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and redirect.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("users", $con);
// get id
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
// prepare query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE id = $id");
// fetch
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
// add click
$newclicks = $result['clicks'] + 1;
// execute
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET clicks = $newclicks WHERE id = $id");
// close
mysql_close($con);
// redirect
header('Location: '. $result['twitter']);
?>
```

Comment: -1 The OP wants to do this using jQuery, your answer is not a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to attach a click event handler to the links. To do that, they will need some common identifier (in this case it will probably be best to give all the Twitter links a common class name. I'll use `twitter` as an example). Then you can use jQuery's [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method to bind the event handler, and fire an AJAX request to your PHP script that actually updates the database:

```
$(".twitter").click(function() {
    $.post("script.php", {
        user: theClickedUserId //I'm assuming you'll want to pass in something to your script here
    }, function() {
        //Done!
    }
});
```

Comment: am not understanding your answer :(
script.php is for ?

Comment: `script.php` is a PHP file which contains the code to actually update the database.